# RegExp match all

Tags: javascript, regex

For some reason I can't seem to get `RegExp` to match all occurrences. It's late, I'm sure I'm doing something incorrect, so any help would be great!

#### HTML

```
<li><a href='/index.php?id=1769'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li>
<li><a href='/index.php?id=3812'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li>
<li><a href='/index.php?id=4962'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows XP; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li>
<li><a href='/index.php?id=3695'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; U) Opera 6.05  [en]</a></li>
```

#### JS

```
const src = document.body.innerHTML;
const reg = />(Mozilla[^<]+)/gm;
const res = reg.exec(src);
```

[Live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/85668bzu/)

Comment: I've just tested it and it's working!

Comment: It's only showing the first match for myself, I want a list of every match.

Comment: Use `const res = src.match(reg);`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - That doesn't return the first capturing group for each match though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to iterate over the `li` elements individually. Then you can use the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to parse the `textContent` property (as opposed to parsing HTML directly).

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li');
Array.from(elements).forEach(function (element) {
  var match = element.textContent.match(/^(Mozilla.*)/g);

  if (match) {
    console.log(match);
  }
});
```

```html
<li><a href='/index.php?id=1769'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3812'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4962'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows XP; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3695'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; U) Opera 6.05  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2875'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows ME; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li><br><br><a href='/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Opera&vers=6.05'>More Opera 6.05 user agents strings --&gt;&gt;</a><br /></ul><h4>Opera 6.04</h4><ul><li><a href='/index.php?id=2193'>Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3775'>Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3961'>Opera/6.04 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2888'>Opera/6.04 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2211'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 98; U)  [en-GB]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3570'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1767'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2929'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3360'>Mozilla/4.78 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4025'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [fr]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4254'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3581'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3220'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT 4.0) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4104'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.04  [pl]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3508'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3664'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4495'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1415'> Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1338'> Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1563'> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><br><br><a href='/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Opera&vers=6.04'>More Opera 6.04 user agents strings --&gt;&gt;</a><br /></ul><h4>Opera 6.03</h4><ul><li><a href='/index.php?id=4949'>Opera/6.03 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=5776'>Opera/6.03 (Windows 98; U) [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2883'>Opera/6.03 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4375'>Opera/6.03 (Linux 2.4.18-18.7.x i686; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1872'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4955'>Mozilla/5.0 (Linux 2.4.18-18.7.x i686; U) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2195'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1873'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3848'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.20-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4951'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.19-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2223'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.18-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li>
```

---

However, if you decide not to iterate over the elements, then you can just use the [`.match()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) in place of `.exec()` like you originally were. However, you wouldn't be able to get all the capturing groups since you're using a global match.

```js
var reg = />(Mozilla[^<]+)/gm;
console.log(document.body.innerHTML.match(reg));
```

```html
<li><a href='/index.php?id=1769'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3812'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4962'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows XP; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3695'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; U) Opera 6.05  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2875'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows ME; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li><br><br><a href='/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Opera&vers=6.05'>More Opera 6.05 user agents strings --&gt;&gt;</a><br /></ul><h4>Opera 6.04</h4><ul><li><a href='/index.php?id=2193'>Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3775'>Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3961'>Opera/6.04 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2888'>Opera/6.04 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2211'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 98; U)  [en-GB]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3570'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1767'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2929'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3360'>Mozilla/4.78 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4025'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [fr]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4254'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3581'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3220'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT 4.0) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4104'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.04  [pl]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3508'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3664'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4495'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1415'> Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1338'> Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1563'> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><br><br><a href='/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Opera&vers=6.04'>More Opera 6.04 user agents strings --&gt;&gt;</a><br /></ul><h4>Opera 6.03</h4><ul><li><a href='/index.php?id=4949'>Opera/6.03 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=5776'>Opera/6.03 (Windows 98; U) [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2883'>Opera/6.03 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4375'>Opera/6.03 (Linux 2.4.18-18.7.x i686; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1872'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4955'>Mozilla/5.0 (Linux 2.4.18-18.7.x i686; U) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2195'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1873'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3848'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.20-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4951'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.19-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2223'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.18-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li>
```

---

If you want all the capturing groups, use the [`.exec()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and increment the `lastIndex` property to get the next match. In the snippet below, the first capturing group is logged.

```
var reg = />(Mozilla[^<]+)/gm;
var match;

while ((match = reg.exec(document.body.innerHTML)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === reg.lastIndex) {
        reg.lastIndex++;
    }

    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Snippet:

```js
var reg = />(Mozilla[^<]+)/gm;
var match;

while ((match = reg.exec(document.body.innerHTML)) !== null) {
    if (match.index === reg.lastIndex) {
        reg.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

```html
<li><a href='/index.php?id=1769'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3812'>Opera/6.05 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4962'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows XP; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3695'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 4.0; U) Opera 6.05  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2875'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows ME; U) Opera 6.05  [de]</a></li><br><br><a href='/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Opera&vers=6.05'>More Opera 6.05 user agents strings --&gt;&gt;</a><br /></ul><h4>Opera 6.04</h4><ul><li><a href='/index.php?id=2193'>Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3775'>Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3961'>Opera/6.04 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2888'>Opera/6.04 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2211'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 98; U)  [en-GB]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3570'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1767'>Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2929'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3360'>Mozilla/4.78 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4025'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [fr]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4254'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3581'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3220'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows NT 4.0) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4104'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.04  [pl]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3508'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3664'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4495'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.04  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1415'> Opera/6.04 (Windows XP; U)  [de]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1338'> Opera/6.04 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1563'> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows XP) Opera 6.04  [en]</a></li><br><br><a href='/pages/useragentstring.php?all=TRUE&name=Opera&vers=6.04'>More Opera 6.04 user agents strings --&gt;&gt;</a><br /></ul><h4>Opera 6.03</h4><ul><li><a href='/index.php?id=4949'>Opera/6.03 (Windows NT 4.0; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=5776'>Opera/6.03 (Windows 98; U) [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2883'>Opera/6.03 (Windows 2000; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4375'>Opera/6.03 (Linux 2.4.18-18.7.x i686; U)  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1872'>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows 2000; U) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4955'>Mozilla/5.0 (Linux 2.4.18-18.7.x i686; U) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2195'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=1873'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 2000) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=3848'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.20-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=4951'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.19-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li><li><a href='/index.php?id=2223'>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Linux 2.4.18-4GB i686) Opera 6.03  [en]</a></li>
```

Comment: I didn't provide context, but I'm scraping from a server so looping over nodes is not the best idea. But yeah, `String.prototype.match` was what I was after. A total brain fart. Thanks for the in-depth answer!